# django ManyToMany models views and templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have the Gammer model that is User extension and the Competition model. many users can play a competition and a competition can have many users (ManyToMany)

```
class Gammer(User):

    competition=models.ManyToManyField(Competition)
    puntaje_global = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ranking = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Competition(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    finish_date=models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    duration = models.DurationField(blank=True,null=True)
    def finish(self):
        self.finish_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()
    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Add in admin.py:

```
admin.site.register(Gammer)
```

The admin can view player competitions (users) or assign them competencies

Now I want the players (users) can register the competitions(choose competitions).
How do I continue?

Comment: you mean that every thing is working from the admin but you want to allow users too?

Answer (score 0):

Question is not entirely clear. Since its registered in admin you can go to the admin page and from the gammer profile you can choose the competitions available from available options. 
But if you are planning to provide the users with option to choose their competitions then you need to build a utility where they can choose from.